# Is it worth while to get extra leg-room when travelling on a 16 hour flight, on a 777-300ER?

Tags: seating, aircraft, boeing

This is my first time flying from India to Chicago (USA). I am 6’5” so I'm thinking of getting a seat with extra leg room. I have 2 options with where to sit:

1. 17A - The row infront of which there are the places where there is extra space for a baby's crib.
2. 27A - The row facing the toilets.

I need some help with which seat would be best, especially in regards to the lavatorie noises and smells on a [777-300ER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_777#777-300ER).
Plane seat layout:

[image: 777 Airplane Seat layout]

Comment: The commonly-used reference for determining airline seat issues is [Seat Guru](https://www.seatguru.com).

Comment: The first rows will usually have several drawbacks: while you’ll have more space at knee level, you often have less space at foot level (there’s no seat in front of you where you can put your feet under). The tray table and/or video equipment is also often in the armrest, which is thus ticker and unmovable. Details are airline-specific (and sometimes specific to a particular version of the airplane), check Seat Guru for details.

Comment: Having space for bassinets often means babies near you during the flight.

Comment: I am also 6'5" and would like to emphasize the importance of @jcaron's comment. It is often easier to sleep if you have room to straighten your legs (or nearly so) beneath the seat in front of you than it is with a bulkhead preventing this. This makes emergency exit rows seem appealing, but those seats typically do not recline. A related problem is being by the window, where the curvature of the fuselage can make the floor area too narrow for comfort. Bulkhead seats by an exit door usually have great legroom but that of the adjacent seat can be limited by the housing for the inflatable slide.

Comment: No plane map attached as far as I can see. There are LOTS of different 777-300ER configurations.  Flyertalk has whole threads dedicated on where to sit on a specific aircraft. For example the thread for Uniteds' 777-300ER is at https://www.flyertalk.com/forum/united-airlines-mileageplus/1807844-everything-you-want-know-about-where-sit-777-300er.html

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an Air India 777-300ER https://www.seatguru.com/airlines/Air_India/Air_India_Boeing_777-300ER.php

The good news is that it's a 3-3-3 configuration which is reasonably comfortable. In contrast the newer "high density" 777 have 3-4-3 which is a miserable experience.

If you haven't yet, read the reviews on seatguru for both of your proposed seats. There are plenty of comments for these two rows specifically and it's fairly mixed. Draw your own conclusions.

Personally I would go with an aisle seat in the middle column at least 4 rows away from the nearest galley or bathroom.

1. It's generally the quietest area of the plane
2. You have direct aisle access if you need to go to the bathroom or just want to stretch your legs a bit.
3. Middle seats in the middle column are the last seats fill up. That maximizes your chances of having an empty seat next to you.
4. It minimizes the number of times you have to get up to let someone else out. Even if the middle seat isn't empty, there is a good chance it's a couple, so they won't bother you. I don't mind letting people out but it can be cumbersome if I'm working and fully strapped in with power supply, laptop, mouse & headsets or when I'm trying to sleep.

Bulkheads have significant pros and cons. The area tends to be the busiest and noisiest in the plane. It's difficult to store your stuff around your feet and it's a no-no during take of and landing. Often the entertainment system is in the armrest and not available during take of landing. The seats can be harder and may not have reclined. Sometimes the seats next to the exits are quite cold (since the insulation in the door isn't all that great).

Rows 21 A-C/H-K and row 41 have the best legroom. I'd stay away from row 17 and  27D-F. These have a hard bulkhead in front of them. While they may have technically more "leg room", the room is less usable since you can't shove your feet under the seat in front of you.

So overall it's a bit of a trade-off about what matters most to you.

Comment: I was choosing 27A , which is close to the exit BUT also close to the lavatories. What would you say regarding the lavatories problem .

Comment: Depends on how full the flight is. It's a very long flight, so there will be less of a rush hour which long lines in front of the loo. However, on these long flights people often get up and stand for a while to stretch their legs. In front of 27A is the prime spot of doing that. Hard to predict.